# Filtering out the database for multiple foreign key

Tags: python, django, message

Here's my Model

```
class Message(models.Model):
sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
```

How can I filter out the messages between two users?
I did something like this, it's giving the messages separately, I couldn't filter out them in one list as we see on social sites.

```
data1 = Message.objects.filter(sender_id=id, receiver_id=request.user.id)
data2 = Message.objects.filter(receiver_id=id, sender_id=request.user.id)
```

Please help me with this code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) in this case. Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

data = Message.objects.filter(
    Q(sender_id=id,receiver_id=request.user.id) | Q(sender_id=request.user.id,receiver_id=id)
)
```

Comment: does this draw the same result?:
 
```data1 = Message.objects.filter(sender_id__in=[id, request.user.id], receiver_id__in=[id, request.user.id])```

Comment: I think that one als gets messages from someone to themselves, but those messages most likely don't exist.

Comment: @Reza Yes if users can't send message to themselves. In case if they can, in your query you also will see message from request.user.id to request.user.id for example.

Comment: Awesome! Along with order_by(id) working out exactly as it should. Thank You Sir AyumuKasuga. It's a honor for me to join this Great Community!